# What are some good ways to benchmark a REST api service?

Tags: google-chrome, rest, benchmarking

Currently I use the [REST Console extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn/related)  for Google Chrome to see the JSON responses. I really like this client because it allows me to send authenticated requests that would otherwise not work for a anonymous request.

Are there any tools that I can use similar to this where I can benchmark the performance of my server?

For example returning the average response time, response time when under stress(1000 requests/sec).

What tools can I use that will be able to provide me with this information for a REST api service? I've looked into Jmeter but I don't think there is a Chrome plugin for it. I'm looking for a open ended answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ab is one of the widely used apache benchmarking tool.

It provides the results in the format you are looking for with the kind of load you want to generate.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html